# tweetsharp and api streaming?

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I can't find a recent answer on this.

Tweetsharp reportedly in a number of old posts  does not support streaming from the Twitter user stream api. However github shows a class which looks like it does support streaming.

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/cad16546df7c5be6ee528ecfa6171098b662a6ab/src/net40/TweetSharp.Next/Service/TwitterService.Streaming.cs

Does tweetsharp now supports streaming from Twitter, where it did not before

I'm learning c# and I'd appreciate the view of an experienced coder before i continue to spend hours working with tweetsharp.

Comment: Good point. Does tweetsharp now supports streaming from Twitter, where it did not before

Comment: This might help you out: [**TweetSharp - Where did FluentTwitter go?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587176/where-did-fluenttwitter-go)

Comment: @Damo add it to your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you search for is only [Twitter's streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods), you can implement it without a need for an external library

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"); 
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");
webRequest.Timeout = -1;
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
while (true)
{
    var line = responseStream.ReadLine();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

    dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(line);

    if(obj["user"]!=null) 
        Console.WriteLine(obj["user"]["screen_name"] + ": " +  obj["text"]);

}
```

Comment: why would you `obj["user"]["screen_name"]` instead of `obj.user.screen_name` when using dynamic?

Comment: I was starting to consider this. Thanks for the example, ill try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, things aren't so simple anymore. v1.1 of the API is required, and uses OAuth only. Does anyone know where to find a status/sample.json reader in C# that uses OAuth?