# Twitter Oauth in C#

Tags: c#, twitter, webclient

I'm new to C# and I have a project where I use the Twitter Search Api. In this project I'm programming a "app" where I search Twitter for tweets. First it worked all fine with the query http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23dwdd, like this:

```
     string search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23";

           var JSONEHdata = w.DownloadString(search);
```

Here is "w" a WebClient(), and I use the newtonsoft.dll to get the right information.

But now the api is upgraded to v1.1 and I'll have to use Oauth. I have no experience with this at all.

Can you put this Oath in the header of the WebClient? And how?

Help me guys :')

Frank

Answer (score 0):

The best answer and example I've found on this is here [Using Twitter OAuth via API 1.1 without 3rd Party Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391516/2602178). It was incredibly useful when I was doing something similar and the code is fairly straight forward to follow.