# How to get twitter user_timeline using Mono?

Tags: c#, twitter, mono

I use [Bobby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391516/1031200) to fetch the user timeline of Twitter, the code is very simple to understand, and I tried under Windows/.NET 4.5, it works very well.

But when I attempt to use the exactly same code to run on Ubuntu/Mono 2.10, it throws an exception:

```
System.Net.WebException has been thrown
Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailur
```

It seems Mono cannot add OAuth header to the http request, so is there any good approach to fetch twitter user timeline using Mono?

Here's the StackTrace:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.Exception: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.Exception: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at test1.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00207] in /home/jerry/test1/test1/Main.cs:89
```

Comment: Did you look at the post following bobbys answer ? Basically see the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is my final solution, import SSL cerificates:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

It solved my problem.