# Correct URL for getting Twitter timeline

Tags: jquery, twitter

I am having difficulty returning any JSON from the Twitter API. All I want to do is get my Twitter feed as JSON, and have tried to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/user_timeline/johnrobertpett.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function() {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The resource URL you have used for fetching user feeds is in incorrect format. It should be as follows :
  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=johnrobertpett.json

Please refer the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 2):

You can use [oauth.io](https://oauth.io) to do the client side calls to the twitter api:

```
OAuth.initialize('...oauth.io public key...');
OAuth.popup('twitter', function (err, res) {
    res.get({
        url: '/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json',
        success: function(data) {
            // data contains the tweets
        }
    );
});
```

You can see the full example displaying the home timeline: http://jsfiddle.net/KxCs2/1/

(the `.get` has the same syntax than the $.ajax, so you can use either the success callback or deferred `.done` as in the example...)

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention how you resolved the back-end side. With API 1.1 you need to have a new application on Twitter-Dev. And then on the serverside, you must send your authentication info to get your JSON. If you haven't yet, please see following posts:

**FOR C#**
[Using Twitter OAuth via API 1.1 without 3rd Party Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049927/using-twitter-oauth-via-api-1-1-without-3rd-party-library/15391516#15391516)

**For PHP**
[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1)
This answer will help you.