# Post twitter status with url using twitter REST API 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post a status from website to a Twitter account and succeeded using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json API and with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049927/using-twitter-oauth-via-api-1-1-without-3rd-party-library).

When I try to add another parameter `URL` like `&url= http://t.co/ReadMore&expended_url=https://www.google.com` included with the status to post on twitter it gives error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Can some one guide me how to add URL parameters with status? I searched a lot but not succeeded.

Comment: dealing with the actual Twitter API could be tricky use a library such as tweetinvi  which would make your life much easier

Comment: @Coder1409: i know but this is an actual way to do work .. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [API documentation for that endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update), you'll see that it does not accept arbitrary parameters. The only parameters allowed are `status`, `in_reply_to_status_id`, `possibly_sensitive`, `lat`, `long`, `place_id`, `display_coordinates`, `trim_user`, `media_ids`. If you want to add a url as part of the tweet, you'll need to encode it and include it in the "status" parameter.